# Accessing remote data with .htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I'm developing an app with php and html5 and I want to access some data from my remote server via ajax. I read from the web and learnt I had to include .htaccess at the root level of my remote server which I've done that but when I try to access from info it gives me this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost`' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I'm using chrome for debugging the app.

This is how my files look:

.htaccess

```
# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# </IfModule>
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#read').load('http://mywebsite/appsfolder/sample.php');

});
```

Comment: Why have you commented out the header directive?

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 404" - Even uncommented, this header may not be set on a default 404 response. Try changing it to `Header always set ...`

Comment: Since you are loading a remote PHP script via Ajax, wouldn't it be simpler to use a `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")` in the PHP code ? It would allow you to limit remote access to that script only, instead of the contents of the whole directory the .htaccess is in.

Comment: yes, i've removed the commented line and its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Samurai8 mentioned in a comment, uncomment (that is, remove the '#' from the beginning of each line) the part of your .htaccess file that you posted. Your server will only send the header when that block is uncommented.